# Conditional Expectation from a joint pdf

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

> Suppose that both $X$ and $Y$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$ and $Y$ has mariginal density $f(y)=\int_{\mathbb R}f(x,y)dx$. The conditional density of $X$ given $Y$ is given by $f(x|y)=\dfrac{f(x,y)}{f(y)}$ and $E(X|Y=y)=\int_{\mathbb R}xf(x|y)dx$. Let $\sigma(Y)$ be the sigma field generated by $Y$ and show that $E(X|\sigma(Y))=\theta(Y)$ where $\theta(y)=E(X|Y=y)$

My question here is what is $\theta(Y)$? Is it $E(X|Y=Y)$ and if so what does this mean?

I know I need to show that $$ \int_AE(X|\sigma(Y)dP=\int_A\theta(Y)dP \;\;\; \forall\; A\in\sigma(Y) $$
but im unsure how to start since im unclear on what $\theta(Y)$ means.

Comment: $\theta (Y)$ is a r.v. s.t. $\mathbb E[\theta (Y)]=\mathbb E[X]$. It's the best approximation of $X$ knowing $Y$ is measurable. Normally, we write $\theta (Y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$.

Comment: $\theta$ must be looked at as a function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ prescribed by $y\mapsto\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$. Then $\theta(Y)$ is just the composition $\theta\circ Y:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. The interpretation $\theta(Y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=Y]$ is confusing and must be avoided.

Comment: @drhab so I should think of $\theta(Y)$ as $\theta(Y)(\omega)=E(X|Y=y)$ where $Y(\omega)=y$?

Comment: @alpast: No ! as $\theta (Y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$, where $\theta : y\mapsto \mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$ is a function. When $f(x)=x^2$, how do you think $f(X)$ ? as $X^2(\omega )=x^2$ ? Of course not :)

Comment: @idm sorry I dont understand? I get that $\theta : y\mapsto \mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$. And then $\theta(Y)$ is the composition of $Y$ and $\theta$, so $\theta(Y(\omega)) : \omega\mapsto \mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$. is this right?

Comment: $\theta(Y(\omega))=\mathbb{E}[X\mid \sigma(Y)](\omega)$ for all $\omega\in \Omega$.

Comment: @alpast It is indeed correct that $\theta(Y)(\omega)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=Y(\omega)]$

Comment: @idm I disagree with the "No!" in your second comment. Indeed $\theta(Y)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ (as shown in my answer), but if $y$ stands for $Y(\omega)$ then it is true that $\theta(Y)(\omega)=\mathbb E[X\mid Y=y]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here $\theta:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is prescribed by:$$y\mapsto\mathbb E[X\mid X=y]=\int xf(x\mid y)\;dx$$

So actually: $$\theta(Y)=\int xf(x\mid Y)\;dx$$

From here it is our intention to prove that $\theta(Y)$ has the *characteristics* of $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ which are:

- $\theta(Y)$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$.
- $\mathbb E\mathbf1_AX=\mathbb E\mathbf1_A\theta(Y)$ for every $A\in\sigma(Y)$

Be aware that $\mathbb E[X\mid Y]$ is the same thing as $\mathbb E[X\mid \sigma(Y)]$.

---

It is immediate that $\theta(Y)$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$.

Further we have: $$A\in\sigma(Y)\iff A=\{Y\in B\}\text{ for some Borel set }B$$

With this in mind we find:

$$\mathbb E\mathbf1_A\theta(Y)=\mathbb E\mathbf1_B(Y)\theta(Y)=\int f(y)1_B(y)\theta(y)\;dy=\int f(y)1_B(y)\left[\int xf(x\mid y)\;dx\right]\;dx\;dy=$$$$\int\int 1_B(y)xf(x,y)\;dx\;dy=\mathbb E\mathbf1_B(Y)X=\mathbb E\mathbf1_AX$$

Now we are done and this together justifies to state that $$\mathbb E[X\mid \sigma(Y)]=\mathbb E[X\mid Y]=\theta(Y)$$

Comment: Why is $\theta(Y)$ measurable w.r.t. $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: It is direct that $Y$ is measurable wrt $\sigma(Y)$. Then $\theta(Y)$ also because the preimage of a Borel set $B$ under $\theta\circ Y$ takes the form $Y^{-1}(\theta^{-1}(B))$ where $\theta^{-1}(B)$ is again a Borel set, so the preimage is element of $\sigma(Y)$. More shortly $\{\theta(Y)\in B\}=\{Y\in\theta^{-1}(B)\}\in\sigma(Y)$.

Comment: Sure. But is why $\theta$ (Borel) measurable?

Comment: @RobertW. That is indeed a good question. It goes back to something like: if $g(x,y)$ is a measurable function then also $x\mapsto\int g(x,y)dy$ is a measurable function. It is treated by proving Fubini. I am not quite willing to go deeper into this here.